# Getting started with SSO using Sustainsys

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I need to setup a custom Identity Provider using SAML 2.0. Problem is I don't really know where to start. I want to ultimately integrate this into an existing .NET 4 project, but in the mean time I've been trying to get this setup in a new, empty project.

And when I say "start" I mean from the very beginning. It seems that you have to have something with OWIN setup, but that may just be something else. I've looked at Sustainsys and OneLogin and they seem to base their examples on knowing a lot more than I do.

FWIW, we're trying to integrate with Brightcove as they offer SSO via SAML. They state that they work with OneLogin and others. They provide some fields and information such as:

- Endpoint - I know what this is.
- X.509 cert - I know what it is and I think I've created one on the Onelogin site. I've pasted it into Brightcove. Not sure what I need to do locally. I have the private key, X.509, and CSR.
- SAML Issuer/Entity ID Override - Says it's provided by the SSO provider, which is me, which I don't know. This is what Brightcove says:

  > By default Gallery uses the ID of your access control profile, but you can override it here.
- ACS URL Override - I think I understand this. After a validate the login this is where I send them back.
- SAML AuthnContext Override - Has a default value: `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:AC:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport` Not sure if I need to match this somewhere or if I should override it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Sustainsys.Saml2 library is an SP implementation only. Unless you know SAML2 well, it cannot be used to implement an Idp.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for how to setup a IdP in .NET?

Comment: @AndersAbel I'm in the same situation. How would it be used if one does know SAML2 well? There is the Stub Idp so it seems it can be done, but that doesn't look production-ready so far. I've been looking at source code for a couple days but have not yet found any documentation on the library beyond the Read the Docs configuration. Is there anything else?

Comment: @xr280xr The StubIdp is a testing tool and as you say, it is definitely not production ready. If you know SAML2 well you can use the protocol support in the library to build an Idp. But you would need to add all the AuthnRequest validations required. If you're interested in contributing along path, please mail me for discussions.

Comment: I ended up going with a commercial 3rd party. For our company it was relatively inexpensive given the lack of knowledge on the topic. The cost is mostly for support. They spent 1.5 hours on the phone just to setup a proof of concept. From that I was able to implement it into a production environment by myself, but they said if I needed more help just to call.